# .Net 5.0 Core Project - Add Framework / metapackage to it?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to make library to share code amongst multiple web applications so I want to add the how can I add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to a .net 5.0 core class library, how can I do this?  If I change the .csproj file to change project SDK to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web it will include it, but then it wants a main() function and rather not do this.

Answer (score 1):

OK i figured it out:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio